# To find the maximum number of items with particular conditions

Tags: python, mongodb

So I have two documents - Shop(X,Y,Z) and nocs(stands for the number of candies sold by the particular shop-A,B,C).How do I find the type of candy was sold the most by shop X.
Each entry is when a customer buys a candy. When the candy is sold,the shop name is entered and which candy was bought by the customer.The data is given for the first 1200 customers.

Comment: Hi. Please show us what you have done so far and lets start from there.

Comment: How is your data represented in Python?

Comment: Please put example of your mongo document.